# javascript to set value of a lookup field

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery

I have 5 values in my lookup column. I need to select one and show it there by default.

```
document.getElementById("IdofLookupField").value="Country";
```

But this is not working, this doesn't set the value of lookup field as Country. Country is already a value in that lookup column.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp

Comment: can you try `document.querySelector("[title=ColumnName]").value = IndexOftheCountry;`

Comment: Did you try my answer @vikashkumar

Comment: Not yet @AtishDipongkor.. will try it soon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding some code as you asked in comment.

```
<option value="2">Country< /option>
```

You need the value of the option which has `Country` in `innerHTML`.

Get all options by `title` attribute instead of `id` as `id` always generates dynamically.

```
var allOptions = document.querySelectorAll("[title=Category] option");
```

Now find `Country` and set as selected.

```
var allOptions = document.querySelectorAll("[title=Category] option");

[].some.call(allOptions, function(option) {
    if (option.innerHTML == "Country") {
        option.selected = "selected";
        return true;
    }
});
```

**PS:** Assuming `Category` is the name of the lookup column. Need to change in your case.

Answer (score 2):

For lookup select options, the value of each option is the **Id** of the lookup list item, not the display column value.

```
<option value="2">Country<option>
```

Here, `2` is the Id of the lookup list item that has value `Country` for the lookup display column.

You can use the Id if you want to select by value, or you can try selecting by the display value of the option.

Comment: can u help with the code?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp